# What happens behind the scenes when initializing a const ref string member with a const char*

Tags: c++

If a const string is initialized from a const char*. I assume that a temporary std::string object is created and the reference refers to the temporary object.
Is it correct?

```
#include<string>

struct A{
        const std::string& str_;
        A(const std::string& o):str_(o){}
};

int main(){

        A moshe{"moshe"};

}
```

Comment: If this is an academic question, I'm not sure of the answer.  If this was for my team's project, they'd say `std::string str_;` and `A(std::string o):str_{std::move(o)} {}`.

Comment: It's a simplified version of code that I've seen. It's probably not a rare thing to see, it's very easy to unintentionally write code like this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `const std::string` will be constructed from `const char*` and `const std::string&` field will refer to this temporary `const std::string` which has a scope of the constructor.

Normally a reference extends the lifetime of an object to its own lifetime when it's initialized, however this is an exception ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization))

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference, with the following exceptions:
>
> ...
>
> a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as of DR 1696).

So the temporary `const std::string` will only be in a valid state for the time your `struct` is being constructed. The fact that standard permits it seems to be a known defect ([bottom of this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)).